# ARM template command to find resource id from different resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-image-builder

> **What needs to change in the `resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/images/', parameters('imageName'))` command below in order to successfully retrieve the `id` of an image resource that is located in a DIFFERENT resource group?**

**ERROR:**

When we run an ARM template containing the following code, an error is returned which says that `"The Image '/subscriptions/long-alpha-numeric-subscription-id/resourceGroups/myCurrentResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myimagename' cannot be found in 'westus' region.\ "`.

```
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
"apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
"name": "[parameters('VmName')]",
"location": "[parameters('resourceGroupRegion')]",
"properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": { "vmSize": "Standard_DS1_v2" },
    "storageProfile": {
        "imageReference": { 
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/images/', parameters('imageName'))]"
        },
    ...other stuff
```

**WHAT WORKS:**

However, when we replace the `resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/images/', parameters('imageName'))` command with the explicit Id of the intended image from a DIFFERENT resource group in the same region that we cut and paste from the Azure Portal, the ARM template works fine.

So the image is visible to the process that runs the ARM template, but problem is in the syntax of the `resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/images/', parameters('imageName'))` command.

**WHAT WE NEED:**

If you look carefully at the error message, it says that `"The Image '/subscriptions/long-alpha-numeric-subscription-id/resourceGroups/myCurrentResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myimagename' cannot be found in 'westus' region.\"`

The problem is that it is looking in `myCurrentResourceGroup`, when the image is located in `someOtherResourceGroup` within the same subscription.

> **What command needs to be entered into the ARM template in order for the ARM template to find the image from the DIFFERENT `someOtherResourceGroup` resource group without our needing to paste in the raw id value explicitly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `someOtherResourceGroup` as a parameter and construct the id from there. Something like :

```
resourceId(parameters('someOtherResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Compute/images', parameters('imageName'))
```

See `resourceId()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid). Notice that this `someOtherResourceGroup` has to be in the same subscription, otherwise you have to pass the subscription ID in the same way.